# filtering relationships in neo4js

Tags: neo4j

I am using neo4js to store users as nodes with property as user_id. There is a friend relation from user1 to user 2.

I am trying to find the incomming friend connections on node user2(user_id =2) which are comming from node with user_id=1.

I am using the neography library for the same.
https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography/

```
 u2 = Neography::Node.(id)
 u2.outgoing(:friends).filter("..........")
```

I am not sure what exact filter should be given so that I can filter out the relationships comming from node(s) with user_id=1.

Regards,

Pankaj

Answer (score 1):

You can use a traversal in neo4js to find those relationships.

This is untested code, but you want to do something like this:

```
var promise = somenode.traverse({
    "prune_evaluator": {
        "language": "javascript",
        "body": "position.endNode().getId()!=2;" // Note that this is a string
    }},
    neo4j.traverse.RETURN_RELATIONSHIPS);

promise.then(function(relationships) {
    console.log(relationships);
});
```

The first argument to the traverse method is a traversal object, for full docs on what you can put there, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/rest-api-traverse.html

Comment: thanks, i m getting some issues with the return_filter, could you please provide some link to documentation/tutorial which explains the details of the how to write filters in javascript.